# Remove all non-numeric characters except spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using this regex to get just a number back.

```
Regex.Replace(foo, "[^.0-9]", "")
```

How do I make it not remove spaces?

Comment: Are you accepting periods? Then surely you should also accept `E` and `-`, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's easy:

```
Regex.Replace(foo, "[^.0-9\\s]", "")
```

Comment: Note that `\s` covers several different whitespace characters, not just codepoint 32.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the Regex slightly easier to read with the `@""` terminology (no need to escape the backslash:

```
Regex.Replace(foo, @"[^.0-9\s]", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
[^(.0-9)|( )]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, "[^.0-9\\s]", "");
```